# iPad Open Office Document Types from Pages/Numbers in Registered App

Tags: ios, ipad, ms-office

I have registered my iPad application to accept a number of incoming document types including .xls, .xlsx, .doc and .docx.  I can verify that this works by opening an email attachment with these file types on the iPad and seeing my application as one of the options under "Open In".  My issue is that if I open up one of these documents in Pages or Numbers on the iPad then I do not get this option under "Share and Print".  Am I looking in the wrong place or is the option to share a file with other registered applications not offered by Pages or Numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages and Numbers don't have the ability to open a document in another application.

The easy way is to export them and send an email to yourself.